# ORA-00942 table or view does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a sql query in db oracle
I want to output max value.
SQL query contains unique field values

Sql query below contains duplicate rows:

```
select 
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,field9,MAX(field10) as field10

from(

select 
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,field9,field10

from table

)tabl

GROUP BY field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,field9
```

I corrected sql request but it doesn't work.
Sql query below an error message is displayed :ORA-00942 table or view does not exist.

```
select

field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,field9

,(SELECT MAX(field10)  FROM tabl ) as field10

from(
select 
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,field9,field10

from table
)tabl
```

how can i fix it? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: `,(SELECT MAX(field10)  FROM tabl ) as field10` => You mean `table` not `tabl`?? Because the alias `tabl` is not valid in inner `select` field.

Comment: table is displayed blue because it is a SQL keyword. do you mean the keyword or is it the name of one of your tables?

Comment: The format of your SQL code is rather poor. can you impreove it? is there an line number(column number in your error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your first query **can not** have duplicates, as you are grouping by all columns and using `aggregate` function of remaining column, `field10`.

Now coming back you your error. The reason for error is `,(SELECT MAX(field10)  FROM tabl ) as field10`. Because `tabl` is an alias for outer table and you are using it inside the `select` clause, hence the error.

Also you can further simplify it like below and it will also not give you duplicates.

```
select 
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,
  field7,field8,field9,MAX(field10) as field10
from table
GROUP BY field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,
 field7,field8,field9
```